# Security with sending faxes from pc

Tags: network, fax

I sometimes need to send faxes and thought I would buy a modem for doing this and use Windows Fax and Scan software that comes with Windows 10. Does the type of or specifications of the modem determine if my data will be secure? I don't really understand how security works with faxes. Will the data I send be encrypted when sending a fax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, data sent by fax is not encrypted. A fax is essentially a series of pixels sent as tones over a phone line. If the phone line is secure, the data being sent is exactly as secure as a phone conversation - with exactly the same risks of being overheard, but a slightly different requirement for receiving it. If an attacker can intercept the message, they can get the same output as your intended recipient.

Comment: How can you determine if your phone line is secure?